# Emitting a Node.js Event from a C++ callback function

Tags: javascript, c++, node.js, windows, node.js-napi

In a Node.js application, I need to be notified when the default audio device has been changed. This program will be used on Windows 7.

Currently I am trying to do this by making a C++ add-on for node that, through the IMMNotificationClient::OnDefaultDeviceChanged method from the Windows Core Audio API, emits an event that can be received by a Node event emitter.

Here's an example of how the Windows Core Audio API callback method would look:

```
HRESULT STDMETHODCALLTYPE OnDefaultDeviceChanged(EDataFlow flow, ERole role, LPCWSTR pwstrDeviceID)
{
   //User written code that emits a node Event.
}
```

Here is some ideal c++ style pseudo code of what I would love to have in the above callback function:

```
EventEmitter.emit(v8::String::NewFromUtf8("defaultDeviceChanged"), deviceName);
```

I'm not sure how to make this happen though, so here is my question: How do I emit an event to a Node.js application through a C++ callback function?

I'm open to other solutions as long as they can be run natively on Node (IE through an add-on), and will work on Windows 7, this means external calls to applications like nircmd are off the table.

*EDIT*

This is some experimental code to try and help describe what I am doing:

AudioDeviceEmitter.h:

```
#pragma once

#include <stdio.h>
#include <wchar.h>
#include <tchar.h>
#include <time.h>
#include "windows.h"
#include "Mmdeviceapi.h"
#include "Propidl.h"
#include "Functiondiscoverykeys_devpkey.h"
#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include <comdef.h>
#define NAPI_DISABLE_CPP_EXCEPTIONS
#include <napi.h>
#include <vector>

class AudioDeviceEmitter : public Napi::ObjectWrap<AudioDeviceEmitter>, public IMMNotificationClient {
public:
    static Napi::Object Init(Napi::Env env, Napi::Object exports);
    AudioDeviceEmitter(const Napi::CallbackInfo& info);


    Napi::Value AudioDeviceEmitter::enrollInNotifications(const Napi::CallbackInfo& info);
    Napi::Value AudioDeviceEmitter::unenrollInNotifications(const Napi::CallbackInfo& info);
    //WIN API 
    ~AudioDeviceEmitter()
    {
        if (_pEnumerator != NULL) {
            _pEnumerator->UnregisterEndpointNotificationCallback(this);
            _pEnumerator->Release();
        }
    }


    // IUnknown methods -- AddRef, Release, and QueryInterface

    ULONG STDMETHODCALLTYPE AddRef()
    {
        return InterlockedIncrement(&_cRef);
    }

ULONG STDMETHODCALLTYPE Release()
{
    ULONG ulRef = InterlockedDecrement(&_cRef);
    if (0 == ulRef)
    {
        delete this;
    }
    return ulRef;
}

HRESULT STDMETHODCALLTYPE QueryInterface(
        REFIID riid, VOID **ppvInterface)
    {
        if (IID_IUnknown == riid)
        {
            AddRef();
            *ppvInterface = (IUnknown*)this;
        }
        else if (__uuidof(IMMNotificationClient) == riid)
        {
            AddRef();
            *ppvInterface = (IMMNotificationClient*)this;
        }
        else
        {
            *ppvInterface = NULL;
            return E_NOINTERFACE;
        }
        return S_OK;
    }

    // Callback methods for device-event notifications.
    //------------THIS IS A FUNCTION I AM TRYING TO GET TO WORK----------
    //------------It doesnt currently work, but hopefully shows----------
    //------------        what I'm trying to accomplish        ----------
    HRESULT STDMETHODCALLTYPE OnDefaultDeviceChanged(
        EDataFlow flow, ERole role,
        LPCWSTR pwstrDeviceId)
    {
        if (flow == eRender) {
            _locked = true;

            std::string name = "";
            IMMDevice * pDevice = NULL;
            HRESULT hr = _pEnumerator->GetDevice(pwstrDeviceId, &pDevice);
            if(SUCCEEDED(hr)){

            name = getFriendlyNameString(pDevice);
            pDevice->Release();
        }

        for(int i = 0; i < _stillEnrolled.size(); i++) {
            if(_stillEnrolled.at(i)) {
                Napi::CallbackInfo & info = _enrolledSessions.at(i);
                Napi::Env env = info.Env();
                Napi::Function emit = info.This().As<Napi::Object>()
                    .Get("emit").As<Napi::Function>();

                emit.Call(info.This(), { Napi::String::New(env, "defaultDeviceChanged"), 
                Napi::String::New(env, name.c_str())});
            }
        }

        _locked = false;
    }
        return S_OK;
    }

    HRESULT STDMETHODCALLTYPE OnDeviceAdded(LPCWSTR pwstrDeviceId)
    {
        return S_OK;
    };

    HRESULT STDMETHODCALLTYPE OnDeviceRemoved(LPCWSTR pwstrDeviceId)
    {
        return S_OK;
    }

    HRESULT STDMETHODCALLTYPE OnDeviceStateChanged(
        LPCWSTR pwstrDeviceId,
        DWORD dwNewState)
    {
    return S_OK;
    }

    HRESULT STDMETHODCALLTYPE OnPropertyValueChanged(
        LPCWSTR pwstrDeviceId,
        const PROPERTYKEY key)
    {
        return S_OK;
    }

private:

    std::string getFriendlyNameString(IMMDevice *pDevice) {
        HRESULT hr;
        IPropertyStore *pStore;
        hr = pDevice->OpenPropertyStore(STGM_READ, &pStore);

        PROPVARIANT variant;
        PropVariantInit(&variant);
        hr = pStore->GetValue(PKEY_Device_FriendlyName, &variant);
        size_t strlen = wcslen((wchar_t *)variant.pwszVal);
        int throwAwaylen;
        char *pOutBuffer = (char *)malloc(strlen);
        wcstombs_s((size_t *)&throwAwaylen, pOutBuffer, size, wideCharArray, size);

        std::string toReturn = pOutBuffer;

        free(pOutBuffer);

        PropVariantClear(&variant);
        pStore->Release();

        return toReturn;

    }

    LONG _cRef;
    IMMDeviceEnumerator *_pEnumerator;
    static Napi::FunctionReference constructor;

    std::vector<Napi::CallbackInfo> _enrolledSessions;
    std::vector<bool> _stillEnrolled;
    bool _locked;

};
```

AudioDeviceEmitter.cpp

```
#include "AudioDeviceEmitter.h"

Napi::FunctionReference AudioDeviceEmitter::constructor;

Napi::Object AudioDeviceEmitter::Init(Napi::Env env, Napi::Object exports) {
  Napi::HandleScope scope(env);

  Napi::Function func = DefineClass(env, "AudioDeviceEmitter", {
    InstanceMethod("enrollInNotifications", &AudioDeviceEmitter::enrollInNotifications),
    InstanceMethod("unenrollInNotifications", &AudioDeviceEmitter::unenrollInNotifications)
  });

  constructor = Napi::Persistent(func);
  constructor.SuppressDestruct();

  exports.Set("AudioDeviceEmitter", func);
  return exports;
}

AudioDeviceEmitter::AudioDeviceEmitter(const Napi::CallbackInfo& info)
: Napi::ObjectWrap<AudioDeviceEmitter>(info), _locked(false), _cRef(1),
        _pEnumerator(NULL)
    {
        HRESULT hr = CoInitialize(NULL);

        hr = CoCreateInstance(__uuidof(MMDeviceEnumerator), NULL,
            CLSCTX_ALL, __uuidof(IMMDeviceEnumerator), (void**)&_pEnumerator);

        _pEnumerator->RegisterEndpointNotificationCallback(this);
    }

    //------------THIS IS A FUNCTION I AM TRYING TO GET TO WORK----------
    //------------It doesnt currently work, but hopefully shows----------
    //------------        what I'm trying to accomplish        ----------
Napi::Value AudioDeviceEmitter::enrollInNotifications(const Napi::CallbackInfo& info) {
    while(_locked){}

    _locked = true;
    int currentPos = _enrolledSessions.size();
    _enrolledSessions.push_back(info);
    _stillEnrolled.push_back(true);
    _locked = false;

    while(_stillEnrolled.at(currentPos)){}

    return Napi::String::New(info.Env(), "OK");
}


    //------------THIS IS A FUNCTION I AM TRYING TO GET TO WORK----------
    //------------It doesnt currently work, but hopefully shows----------
    //------------        what I'm trying to accomplish        ----------
Napi::Value AudioDeviceEmitter::unenrollInNotifications(const Napi::CallbackInfo& info) {
    while(_locked){}

    for(int i = 0; i < _enrolledSessions.size(); i++) {
        if (info.This() == _enrolledSessions.at(i).This()) {
            _stillEnrolled.at(i) = false;
        }
    }

    return Napi::String::New(info.Env(), "OK");
}
```

binding.cpp:

```
#include <napi.h>
#include "AudioDeviceEmitter.h"

Napi::Object InitNAPI(Napi::Env env, Napi::Object exports) {
    AudioDeviceEmitter::Init(env, exports);
    return exports;
}

NODE_API_MODULE(WinDefaultAudioDevice, InitNAPI)
```

This code throws errors and doesn't compile, it is here to hopefully explain my problem more fully.

Comment: Hi, the easier solution to me would be to compile your C++ code in a Node.js as a kind of pipeline, then the remain is just Node.js usually code.

Comment: @HoCo_ Thanks for your suggestion, do you have a link to an example on how to do this?

Comment: you have module for Node.js which do the job, I let you dive in the subject to find what according the more to your needs

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Implement one of Nan's AsyncWorker classes. For some example code on how to do so, [look at this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50917212/6872935). after implementing the worker, assign a callback function to the async worker.

Comment: Is there a solution using NAPI?

Comment: @Paleo Yes, there is. Have you already figured it out/asked another question?